# Why does printing a scriptPubKey have an extra OP_PUSHBYTES_20?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, script, p2pkh, opcodes

I am building a P2PKH script pubkey in code, and the standard format is:

`OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <PUBKEYHASH> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`

However, when I print it (I'm using the `bitcoin` Rust crate) it returns as:

`Script(OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 <PUBKEYHASH> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG)`

Is that `OP_PUSHBYTES_20` meaningful? What does it mean? Why is it added?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84767/what-is-the-use-of-op-pushbytes

Comment: @Prayank, perfect thanks!